# How to make LibreOffice Base reconnect to a database

Tags: openoffice.org, libreoffice, openoffice-base, libreoffice-base

I am using LibreOffice Base as a generic database client. Sometimes it loses its connection to some database. Is there a way to reconnect it? I mean, a way other than closing and reopening Base?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't test it, but base allows for connection pooling (`Tools` -> `Options` -> `LibreOffice Base` -> `Connections`):

[image: connections]

Did you try to enable pooling together with a long timeout?

Comment: That does not sound like a solution. For example, I frequently connect to a database at work and then go home. I would prefer to just click on one button the next day to reconnect, instead of closing and reopening Base. I don't believe such parameters could solve this problem, for example.

Comment: ah, ok, then my answer isn't useful in fact - sorry for that!

Comment: No problem, I believe it can be helpful for someone :)